# code for anova model with nesting and crossing in R

Tags: r, nested, interaction, anova

The model I want to construct/test is: dependent variable = factor A + factor B + factor C + interaction between factors A and C + interaction between factors B and C + factor B nested within factor A

An example I came across online is described in the file "ANOVA: advanced designs" (http://web.grinnell.edu/individuals/kuipers/stat2labs/Handouts/DOE%20Advancede.pdf) (thanks to the author(s) for sharing this file online). In this file, the example described in Split Plot/Repeated Measures Designs (slides 9-10) is similar to my case. Here, factor A is brand, factor B is box, and factor C is temp. If we assume (1) box is a fixed effect (i.e. those 3 boxes represent all possible levels of the factor "box"), (2) all bags within each box are assigned to a temp, and (3) there are more than two levels of temperatures (e.g. there are four levels of temperature, 10, 20, 30, 40) and the number of bags within each box assigned to a certain temp is randomly determined (i.e. the numbers of bags assigned to different temperatures are not equal and it could be that no bag is assigned to a certain temperature in some boxes), then this example is almost the same as what I am trying to describe. Also, my design is not balanced.

I want to test which factors and how these factors contribute to the dependent variable. The hypotheses are the hypotheses for a 3-way (in the example of popcorn, brand, temperature, box) anova. In the example of popcorn, the null hypothesis might be: brand, temp and/or box do not influence % popped kernels. The alternative hypothesis is just the opposite to null. Also, probably box in my case could also be a random effect, just as box, but I would like to take both these two situations into consideration (box as fixed and random effect).

What is the appropriate way to address this question?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a very general question and missing some vital information. I would suggest figuring out the statistics first, then the code will be easy to search for.  While you have posted some information about your linear predictor, to specify a model you need to think about what link function you need to implement, which is dependent on the structure of your dependent data. Also it helps to posts example code and data when asking a question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try to edit my question.

Comment: I edited the question and provided an example I found online.

Comment: what hypotheses do you want to test?

Comment: I want to test which factors and how these factors contribute to the dependent variable. The hypotheses are the hypotheses for a 3-way (in the example of popcorn, brand, temperature, box) anova. In the example of popcorn, the null hypothesis might be: brand, temp and/or box do not influence % popped kernels. The alternative hypothesis is just the opposite to null. Also, probably box in my case could also be a random effect, just as box, but I would like to take both these two situations into consideration (box as fixed and random effect). Thanks.

Comment: Are your response data proportions?

Comment: No. The response data are not proportions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure we agree on terminology, but I'll take a shot ...

You say you want

> factor A + factor B + factor C + interaction between factors A and C + interaction between factors B and C + factor B nested within factor A

The main thing to note is that "B nested within A" is equivalent, at least in the world that I'm familiar with, to "include the main effect of A and the interaction between A and B, but not the main effect of B" (i.e. `~A/B == ~A+A:B`.  But then you say you *do* want the main effect of factor B, so this seems a little strange.  Following your specification exactly would give

```
~ A + B + C + A:C + B:C + A/B
```

but this is equivalent to

```
~ A + B + C + A:C + B:C + A + A:B
```

R automatically discards the redundant `A` term, so this is also equivalent to

```
~ A + B + C + A:C + B:C + A:B
```

But since this is essentially the main effects plus all two-way interactions, you could also write it as

```
~(A+B+C)^2
```

Because redundant terms are discarded you could write this equivalently in many different ways: `~A*B+A*C+B*C` (`A*B` is equivalent to `A+B+A:B`) or `~A*C+B*C+A/B` ... if you want to check what R has actually produced, you can use `colnames(model.matrix(my_formula,my_data))`.

This is all assuming we're working in the `lm()`/fixed-effect context ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is very helpful for me! Regarding factor B, it is not necessarily to be included in the model because its effect may actually arise from factor C. Also, it seems that factors B and C are interacting with each other.

Comment: @Ben, this bit of your post sounds wrong to me:"include the main effect of A and the interaction between A and B, but not the main effect of A"". Did you mean "include the main effect of A and the interaction between A and B, but not the main effect of **B** "